# View my Django site hosted in IIS from another computer

Tags: django, windows, iis, windows-firewall, hosted

I have 2 pc and inside all the 2 i have installed Windows 10 pro X64

from hosted pc:
I know Microsoft deprecates Python support on IIS

I developpe my app with django==2.1.*

I have configure IIS to host my django app

I have test, all work like a charm.

I have edit my hosts file and add line in the end of my hosts in system32/...etc 
like this:

```
mycurrenthostedpc_ip   myapp.extranet
```

when i finish imake binding in IIS like this:

```
myapp.extranet --->> host
mycurrenthostedpc_ip ---->>>> IP address
```

I have configure firewall to accept Inbound and port 80

In the hosted PC when icheck

```
http://myapp.extranet/ ---->>> It work well in the hosted pc
```

But when i check in second pc connect to my network like this:

```
http://myapp.extranet/ or http://hosted_pc/myapp.extranet/ ------>>>> Not working
```

How can i correctly  configure my hosted PC if i want to access to my django app (inside another computer) with this url (http://myapp.extranet/)

Thank for advance...

Comment: Install a Linux distribution from the store, and then host your Python based web app on Linux please. Microsoft deprecates Python support on IIS.

Comment: Anything step by step is called a tutorial and off-topic on Stack Overflow.